# Add multiple timecodes to single audio file (.mkv ?) resulting from concatenating several (timecode-based) audio files

Tags: file, audio, ffmpeg, mkv, timecodes

I first converted two .WAV files into .MKV files inserting timecode for each of this file. Then I concatenated these two .MKV files as inputs (each .MKV including one **timecode** inside). However timecodes were not maintained in the final *output*.MKV. I tried:

```
 1. ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv  
 2. mkvmerge -o output.mkv 1.mkv + 2.mkv
```

with `mylist.txt` containing:

```
file '1.mkv'
file '2.mkv'
```

But the final file *output.mkv* resulting from such a concatenation has lost **timecodes** in case 1. In case 2, there is only one **time code** that has been preserved (from input 2.mkv) at the end. According to `mediaInfo` command line. I was expecting 2 times codes issued from 1.mkv and from 2.mkv. But is it the right approach ? (Is it even do-able ?)

To summarize, my goal is to insert multiple **time codes** along with / inside a single audio file (.WAV, or .MKV, or whatever). Here is a sreenshot that technically depicts my purpose [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0lJc.png)

Comment: If the timecode is stored at container-level (most likely), then the final output file, being a single container, can only have one unit of corresponding metadata.

Comment: thanks. However, would that be possible to proceed time codes insertion within one single WAV file, as depicted in my enclosed file. (Otherwise I could introduce silences during the amount of time computed from originally expected time codes)